# How may I change the default imports when creating a C# script in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Whenever I create a C# script in Unity, the file is always headed with the following imports:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
```

Is there any way to add/remove default imports to this list? I can't count how many times I've needed to import `System` by hand just to use a `String`.

Answer (score 2):

There are script templates that you can modify to your liking.

Navigate to your unity install path, mine is..

```
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.0f1
```

Then navigate down through this series of directories

```
\Editor\Data\Resources\ScriptTemplates
```

For the normal template you can modify `81-C# Script-NewBehaviourScript.cs.txt` in any text editor.  Make sure not to remove the items enclosed in hash marks.